# Is there such thing as set of empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

While I'm reading [Is an empty set equal to another empty set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167345/is-an-empty-set-equal-to-another-empty-set), I wonder if `{∅} = ∅`?

And it leads to my doubts : is there such things as "set of empty set" with notation `{∅}`?

If so, then `{∅} = ∅`?

Comment: Related / possible duplicates: [Is ${∅}$ an empty set?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/917467); [Differences in $\varnothing$, {$\varnothing$}, and $\subseteq$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/65599); [$\emptyset={\{\emptyset\}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/270635)

Comment: well, I apologise for not searching thorough enough. Obviously the magic keyword ∅ is so much harder to hit than "empty set" ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of a box. Empty set is like an empty box. But a box with *another* box inside it is no longer empty.

Comment: I used to understand empty set as "nothing". So "Nothing of nothing" is still "nothing". That was my thinking. While understanding empty set as empty box everything makes sense. So "empty set" shouldn't be "nothing" at all?

Comment: That's right, it shouldn't. It's a box with nothing inside it.

Answer (score 5):

$\{\emptyset \}$ has one element, while $\emptyset$ has $0$ elements.

Answer (score 2):

In your language, the empty set can not be "nothing at all" since it is really a mathematical object: a set with no elements, as you understood thanks to the box example. The fact it does not contain anything does not affect the fact it is a set.